# Get package name and parametrized type from a field element - Annotation Processor

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

How can I get `package name`, `generic type` and `Parametrized type` from a `type` from a `field element` in Annotation processor?

Say, if `Element.asType` returns **`java.util.List<String>`**, I want to get

- Package name `java.util`
- Generic type `List<E>` or raw type `List` (preferably raw type)
- Actual Type `String`

Is there any method in `element utils`, `type utils`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Getting the package `java.util`:

```
Element        e   = processingEnv.getTypeUtils().asElement(type);
PackageElement pkg = processingEnv.getElementUtils().getPackageOf(e);
```

Getting the raw type `List`:

```
TypeMirror raw = processingEnv.getTypeUtils().erasure(type);
```

Getting the type arguments e.g. `String`:

```
if (type.getKind() == TypeKind.DECLARED) {
    List<? extends TypeMirror> args =
        ((DeclaredType) type).getTypeArguments();
    args.forEach(t -> {/*...*/});
}
```

See: [`Types.asElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html#asElement-javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror-), [`Elements.getPackageOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Elements.html#getPackageOf-javax.lang.model.element.Element-), [`Types.erasure`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html#erasure-javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror-) and [`DeclaredType.getTypeArguments`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/DeclaredType.html#getTypeArguments--).

Comment: Are there any consequences of comparing `DeclaredType` with `instanceof`  and `element.asType().getKind() == TypeKind.DECLARED)`?

Comment: If you needed to be sure that the type really is a declared type, then `getKind()` probably is more technically correct. The documentation requires that an empty list be returned if there are no type arguments so whether or not it would be an error not to is a bit ambiguous. On the other hand, if you have a `TypeElement`, then you don't need to check since it will always be a `DeclaredType`.